# Finding and Saving Blank Row Location in Python OpenPyXL

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am new to python and need some help understanding why my code continues to run past what I originally believed are the boundaries that I have set for rows and columns:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("x_test.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

emptycellcount = 0
maxrow=50
maxcol=20

for col in ws.iter_cols(min_row = 0, max_row = maxrow):
   for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col = 0, max_col = maxcol): 
      emptycellcount=0
      
      for cell in row:
          if cell.value == None:
              emptycellcount += 1
              print("The presence of an empty row is at " + str(cell.row) + " " + str(cell.column) + " " + str(emptycellcount))

          elif cell.value != None:
              emptycellcount = 0
              emptyrow = cell.row
              print("not empty " + str(cell.row) + " " + str(cell.column) + " " + str(emptycellcount))
              break
```

Right now this code runs through the entire used range of my worksheet "x_text.xlsx" but I would like it to do 3 things:

1. only iterate through a maximum of 20 cells (columns) across 50 rows
2. stop running the code when an entirely empty row is found within the 50x20 cell range
3. save the location of the empty row to the variable "emptyrow" to be referenced again later

I have been working at this for a few days now and have yet to figure out a workable solution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no need to loop `iter_rows()` inside `iter_cols()`. You use one or the other depending on how you want the results.

Comment: Thanks! So I removed iter_cols from the code and its working as you described. However, it still loops to the end of the used range instead of the range that I specify. Would you happen to know how to fix this?

Comment: You probably need to set `max_row=50`: the default is highest row in the worksheet.

Comment: That works! Thank you! I didn't realize max_row was available for iter_rows. Clearly need to get better with the syntax. Could you please post your reply as an answer to the question rather than a comment so I can upvote it?